# Log4j on Apache/Tomcat not working

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, log4j

I'm working on a Java Servlet project. I'm trying to use log4j to log exceptions, methods input and output, etc.

I have added the Jars files and the log4j.properties file.

If I test the Log4j from a test class using Main, it works right. But when I use the Servlet project, the log file is not created.

I'm working on Eclipse with Apache and Tomcat

First, I thought the problem was the log4j.properties file. I move from src directory to Webcontent directory. Then I moved again to classes directory inside Webcontent directory. But I doesn't work.

This is my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.stdout.Append=true

log4j.appender.FILEHIBERNATE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILEHIBERNATE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILEHIBERNATE.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd 
log4j.appender.FILEHIBERNATE.file =logs/Hibernate.log
log4j.appender.FILEHIBERNATE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [Level: %p]%m%n
log4j.appender.FILEHIBERNATE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILEHIBERNATE.Append=true

log4j.appender.springframework=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.springframework.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.springframework.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd 
log4j.appender.springframework.file =logs/springframework.log
log4j.appender.springframework.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [Level: %p]%m%n
log4j.appender.springframework.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.springframework.Append=true

log4j.appender.fidely=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fidely.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fidely.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd 
log4j.appender.fidely.file =logs/Fidely.log
log4j.appender.fidely.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [Level: %p]%m%n
log4j.appender.fidely.Threshold=info,debug
log4j.appender.fidely.Append=true

log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd 
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile.file =logs/customer_area_interfaces/fidelynet3CustomerAreaMobile.log
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [Level: %p]%m%n
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile.Threshold=debug,info,error
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile.Append=true

log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd 
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet.file =logs/customer_area_interfaces/mobile/fidelynet3CustomerAreaMobile.log
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [Level: %p]%m%n
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet.Threshold=debug,info,error
log4j.appender.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet.Append=true

log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate = DEBUG, FILEHIBERNATE
log4j.logger.hibernate = DEBUG, FILEHIBERNATE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = DEBUG, FILEHIBERNATE
log4j.logger.org.springframework = debug, springframework
log4j.logger.fidely = info, fidely
log4j.logger.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile = debug, info, error, fnet3CustomerAreaMobile
log4j.logger.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet = debug, info, error, fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet

log4j.rootLogger = debug
```

And this is the Console:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.info
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "info".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "error".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.info
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "info".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "error".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.info
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "info".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "error".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.info
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "info".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "error".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I don't know to do.
Can you help me?

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Where did you put your log4j.properties and jar?

Comment: Where did u put your log4j.properties file? and can you paste the code which is reading the file?

Comment: Have you added the log4j jar to the project's build path?

Comment: I put the log4j.properties file on SRC folder, then I try on Webcontent and finally on Webcontent/WEB-INF/Classes.

Comment: I have the Jars on Webcontent/WEB-INF/Lib and Program Files/Apache/.../Lib and then added on Eclipse using "Java Build Path"

Comment: I have to put the log4j.properties on "Java Build Path"??.

Answer (score 1):

First put log4j.properties into your **src** folder. If you use **Maven** put it under **src/main/resources**. The file will be automatically detected, if log4j.jar (use version [1.2.16](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j)) is inside the classpath.

Then edit the lines  with: "debug, info, error, ..." to "debug" or "info", because there can only be one log level at a time:

```
log4j.logger.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile = debug, fnet3CustomerAreaMobile
```

The second value has to be the name of the appender.

Check your lib directory for the following jars: **slf4j-api.jar** (adds slf4j), **slf4j-log4j12.jar** (redirects from slf4j to log4j) and **jcl-over-slf4j.jar** (redirects from apache commons-logging to slf4j). The SLF4J version has to be compatible too, use [1.6.4 (newest)](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html). SLF4J is configured automatically by adding and removing the right jars (sadly). Only add the jars mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did everything like you say, but I doesn't work.

Where I have to put the log4j.properties file?
On src folde?
On WebContent/WEB-INF folder?
On WebContent/WEB-INF/Classess folder?

I have to "setup" something on the project to make it find the log4j.properties file?, seting some XML? setting project propereties?

I think that this "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax)." is the Main Problem

Thanks, I will trying some change, buy I really need help

Answer (score 0):

Please check your log. Especially the last two lines:

```
...
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
...
```

I'm quite sure that you're missing some libs in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, see if it helps.

http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

> Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
>
> This error is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
>   class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no
>   appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing
>   one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar,
>   slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class
>   path should solve the problem.
>
> since 1.6.0 As of SLF4J version 1.6, in the absence of a binding,
>   SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.
>
> You can download SLF4J bindings from the project download page.

Answer (score 0):

you have the following problem

```
log4j.logger.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile = debug, info, error, fnet3CustomerAreaMobile
log4j.logger.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet = debug, info, error,fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet
```

If you define a `log4j.logger` the first argument after the = is the `LEVEL`, It can be: `{FATAL,ERROR,WARN,INFO,DEBUG,TRACE}`

The second argument must be the name of an `APPENDER` and nothing else!

But you put `"info"` and `"error"` there and that is wrong!

If you would NOT have defined appender `fnet3CustomerAreaMobile` or appender `fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet` the system would claim for this as well, but that is not the case because you defined those two appenders.

The correct writing is:

```
log4j.logger.fnet3CustomerAreaMobile = debug, fnet3CustomerAreaMobile
log4j.logger.fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet = debug, fnet3CustomerAreaMobileServlet
```

What does that mean? It means that the two defined loggers will report FATAL ERROR WARN INFO and DEBUG log events each at his own defined appender.